# Create See Other response from web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-303

I have a button on website to download a pdf. On click of it, I will hit a `POST API` which will create a lead and redirect to another url (pdf location) on success. I am using `SeeOther Http status` (303) for this.

How can I return 303 response from web api?
How to handle it in jquery ajax?

Current API approach:

```
Response.Headers.add("Location", pdfUrl);
return StatusCode(HttpStstusCode.SeeOther);
```

Not sure how to handle ajax response as it is coming in ajax fail block.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour. If you check the [jQuery source for `$.ajax`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.ajax), you'll see that a request is counted as 'successful' when the HTTP status code is:

```
isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

This is why your 303 response is going in to the `error` handler. You either need to handle the response there, or use a different HTTP response code.